# Cannot open any video files with Blender

Tags: video-sequence-editor, installation

I am completely new to video editing.  After seeing a few Youtube videos, I realised Blender suited my needs well.  Unfortunately, I have failed to open pretty much all kinds of video files.  After reading, old forum/blender.SX posts, I thought my distribution's Blender build did not enable ffmpeg support. So I downloaded the tarball from blender.org, no luck.  Every time I get a message like this on the UI.

> File format is not supported in file '/path/to/file'

It's not that I do not have the codecs, because I regularly re-encode videos with ffmpeg.

**OS:** Fedora 28

**Blender:** Fedora repos, and blender.org tarball

```
$ blender-upstream --version                                 
Blender 2.79 (sub 0)                                
  build date: 2018-03-22                                               
  build time: 14:39:03                                             
  build commit date: 2018-03-22                                                                           
  build commit time: 14:10                                                                                                                                                              
  build hash: f4dc9f9d68b                                                
  build platform: Linux                                                                                                                                                                 
  build type: Release                                                    
  build c flags:  -Wall -Wcast-align -Werror=implicit-function-declaration \
        -Werror=return-type -Werror=vla -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes \
        -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith \
        -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wlogical-op -Wundef -Winit-self \
        -Wnonnull -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits \
        -Wformat-signedness -Wuninitialized -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow \
        -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 \
        -fuse-ld=gold -std=gnu11 -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char \
        -fno-strict-aliasing -msse2
  build c++ flags:  -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-sign-compare \
        -Wlogical-op -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero \
     -Wtype-limits -Werror=return-type -Werror=implicit-function-declaration \
     -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter \
     -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Wformat-signedness -Wuninitialized -Wundef \
     -Wmissing-declarations -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -fuse-ld=gold -std=c++11 \
     -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -msse2
  build link flags:  -Wl,--version-script='/home/sources/blender-release/source/creator/blender.map'
  build system: CMake                                      
$ blender --version                                  
Blender 2.79 (sub 0)                                                                  
  build date: 2018-08-10                                   
  build time: 02:58:43                                                                 
  build commit date: 1970-01-01                         
  build commit time: 00:00                     
  build hash: unknown
  build platform: Linux
  build type: Release
  build c flags:  -Wall -Wcast-align -Werror=implicit-function-declaration \
        -Werror=return-type -Werror=vla -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes \
        -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith \
        -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wlogical-op -Wundef -Winit-self \
        -Wnonnull -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits \
        -Wformat-signedness -Wuninitialized -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow \
        -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -O2 -g -pipe \
        -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS \
        -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches \
        -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 \
        -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic \
        -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -fuse-ld=gold \
        -fopenmp -std=gnu11   -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -msse2
  build c++ flags:  -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-sign-compare \
        -Wlogical-op -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits \
        -Werror=return-type -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-char-subscripts \
        -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wundef \
        -Wformat-signedness -Wuninitialized -Wundef -Wmissing-declarations \
        -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security \
        -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong \
        -grecord-gcc-switches-specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 \
        -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic \
        -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -fuse-ld=gold \
        -fopenmp -std=c++11   -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -msse2
  build link flags:
  build system: CMake
```